# Searching multiple files for list of words in a text file

Tags: linux, grep

I need to go through a huge amount of text files and list the ones that contains ALL of the words listed in another text file.

I need to list only the files containing all of the words. It does not have to be in any specific order. I've tried to use a variety of grep commands, but it only outputs the files containing any of the words, not all of them. It would be ideal to use the txt file containing the list of words as a search for grep.

- Expected output is a list of just the files that succeed in the search (files that contains all the words from the "query" text file)

Tried

`grep -Ffw word_list.txt /*.fas`

`find . -exec grep "word_list.txt" '{}' \; -print`

I've found solutions using a number of pipes like

`awk "/word1/&&/word2/&&/word3/" ./*.txt`

`find . -path '*.txt' -prune -o -type f -exec gawk '/word1/{a=1}/word2/{b=1}/word3/{c=1}END{ if (a && b && c) print FILENAME }' {} \;`

But I have a huge list of words and would be impractical.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the codes/commands you have tried.

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and sorry for being so vague, I edited the question adding some of the codes I've tried to use.

Comment: If you're going to need to do this regularly, you need to think about alternate solutions. Either a gnu-parallel search, or a search engine system, all of which will require extra disk, network and CPU. Good luck.

Comment: Also, ++ for improving your Q, but go one step further and show your required output from your search. Do you want your search just to list file names that succeed? Good luck.

Comment: Added the expected output in the question. Yes, I want a list of just the files that succeeded in the search. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hack as there is no direct way to do AND in grep.. We can using grep -E option to simulate AND.

```
grep -H -E "word1" *.txt| grep -H -E "word2" *.txt|grep -H -E "word3" *.txt | grep -H -E "word4" *.txt| cut -d: -f1 

-H =>  --with-filename
-E => --extended-regexp
cut -d: -f1 => to print only the file name.
```

Comment: Hi @SAB ! Thank you for answering. I did some tests with my files  and it outputs the name of the files containing ANY of the words in the search, not all of them. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Given sample files

```
file1.txt
word1
word2
word4
word5
file2.txt
word1
word2
word3
word4
file3.txt
word2
word3
word4
file4.txt
word0
word1
word2
word3
word4
file5.txt
word0
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
```

This old-fashioned awk/shell code

```
#!/bin/bash

wordList="$1"
shift
awk -v wdListFile="$wordList" '
  BEGIN{
    dbg=0
    while(getline < wdListFile > 0 ) {
      words[$0]=$0
      flags[$0]=0
      numFlags++
    }
  }
  {
    if (dbg) { print "#dbg: myFile=" myFile " FILENAME=" FILENAME }
    if (myFile != FILENAME) {
      # a minor cost of extra reset on the first itteration in the run
      if (dbg) { print "#dbg: inside flags reset" }
      for (flg in flags) {
          flags[flg]=0
      }
    }

    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (dbg) { print "#dbg: $i="$i }
      if ($i in words) {
        flags[$i]++
      }
    }
    matchedCnt=0
    for (f in flags) {
      if (dbg) { print "#dbg: flags["f"]="flags[f] }
      if (flags[f] > 0 ) {
          matchedCnt++
          if (dbg) { print "#dbg: incremeted matchedCnt to " matchedCnt}
      }
    }
    if (dbg) {print "#dbg: Testing matchedCnt=" matchedCnt "==numFlags=" numFlags}
    if (matchedCnt == numFlags) {

      if (dbg) { print "All words found in "FILENAME "matchedCnt=" matchedCnt "  numFlags=" numFlags}
      print FILENAME
      nextfile
    }
    myFile=FILENAME
    if (dbg) { print "#dbg: myFile NOW=" myFile }
  }' $@
```

Run from the command line as

```
./genGrep.sh wd.lst file*.txt
```

Produces the following output

```
file2.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
```

One time only, make the script executable with

```
chmod 755 ./genGrep.sh
```

I would recommend making a copy of this file with `dbg` in the name, then take the original copy and delete all lines with `dbg`. This way you'll have a `dbg` version if you need it, but the `dbg` lines add an extra ~20% to reading the code.

Note that you can switch all `dbg`ing on by setting `dbg=1` OR you can turn on individual lines by adding a `!` char, i.e. `if (! dbg) { ...}`.

If for some reason you're running on really old Unix hardware, the `nextfile` command may not work. See if your system has `gawk` available, or get it installed.
I think there is an trick to getting nextfile behavior if it's not builtin, but I don't want to spend time researching that now.

Note that the use of the `flags[]` array, `matchedCnt` variable and the builtin `awk` function `nextfile` is designed to stop searching in a file once all words have been found.

You could also add a parameter to say "if n percent match, then print file name", but that comes with a consulting rate attached.

If you don't understand the stripped down awk code (removing the `dbg` sections), please work your way thur [Grymoire's Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) before asking questions.

Managing thousands of files (as you indicate) is a separate problem. But to get things going, I would call `genGrep.sh wd.lst A* ; genGrep.sh wd.lst B*; ...` and hope that works. The problem is that the command line has a limit of chars that can be processed at once in filename lists. So if `A*` expands to 1 billion chars, that you have to find a way to break up line size to something that the shell can process.

Typically, this is solved with `xargs`, so

```
find /path/to/files -name 'file*.txt' | xargs -I {} ./genGrep.sh wd.lst {}
```

Will find all the files that you specify by wildcard as demonstrated, from 1 or more `/path/to/file` that you list as the first argument to `find`.
All matching files are sent thru the pipe to `xargs`, which reads all files from list that one command invocation can process, and continues looping (not visible to you), until all files have been processed.

There are extra options to `xargs` that allow having multiple copies of `./genGrep.sh` running, if you have the extra "cores" available on your computer. I don't want to get to deep into that, as I don't know if the rest of this is really going to work in your real-world use.

IHTH

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient solution so far. It also deals correctly with a list that is longer than max command line length (128kB-8MB).

Comment: The use of `xargs` is unsafe: The file `file 3"x2".txt` will mess up. Replace `xargs` with `parallel` from GNU Parallel and it will work.

Comment: @OleTange: Thanks for the comments. I agree that `xargs` can be unsafe, but I think solving the main problem is all the time I can spare. If the O.P. posts a follow on Q I'll try to help fix any issues. Without feedback (or a better defined Q), its not clear what sort of filenames need to be processed. Spaces in filenames will make it blow up, and `\n` chars in the filename (which can happen) won't be good either ;-) .. Will `xargs` have problems with `file 3"x2".txt` if we use `null` termination of filenames, i.e. `find /path -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 ...` ? Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
WORD_LIST=file_with_words.txt
FILES_LIST=file_with_files_to_search.txt
RESULT=file_with_files_containing_all_words.txt

# Generate a list of files to search and store as provisional result
# You can use find, ls, or any other way you find useful
find . > ${RESULT}

# Now perform the search for every word
for WORD in $(<${WORD_LIST}); do
    # Remove any previous file list
    rm -f ${FILES_LIST}
    # Set the provisional result as the new starting point
    mv ${RESULT} ${FILES_LIST}
    # Do a grep on this file list and keep only the files that
    # contain this particular word (and all the previous ones)
    cat ${FILES_LIST} | xargs grep -l > $RESULT
done

# Clean up temporary files
rm -f ${FILES_LIST}
```

At this point you should have in $RESULTS the list of files that contain all the words in ${WORD_LIST}.

This operation is costly, as you have to read all the (still) candidate files again and again for every word you check, so try to put the less frequent words in the first place in the ${WORD_LIST} so you will drop as many files as possible from the checking as soon as possible.